# Highcharts large heat map on official site not working on Chrome

Tags: highcharts

I see that the large heatmap example here:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas

is not working on Chrome, but it is on Firefox. I'm hesitant to get in there and work on a heatmap that might not work on the browser we use the most.

Is anyone working on this, or does someone know what's going on?

Thanks for any help/insight.

I did note that on a few other PCs in my office, the heat map is displaying properly, and the version of Chrome is identical.  Here's data on the one that's not working properly.

I'm using Chrome version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

and here's an image of the blank map and console window.

Any thoughts?

[image: blank heat map on Highcharts website]

Comment: It works fine on Chrome on my machine. What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. So after a few weeks of not working (was working before that), I now notice it displaying fine both on FF and Chrome. Perhaps someone saw this post and fixed it?  In any case, I'll proceed with development. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps. Or maybe it was fixed while fixing some other issue.

Comment: I'll retract my statement. Looks like there are still problems on other PCs in my office when using Chrome.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What problems? Please describe them.

Comment: I posted a picture on my original post.